# Screen change event on Linux desktop

Tags: linux, gtk

I need a conceptual guide on this particular task:

1. I want to be able to select a particular rectangle on Linux desktop
   using two points.
2. Then i want to create one event listener that will wait for some
   graphical change in that particular rectangle
3. Log that change

What would be the quick and dirty way to achieve this if there is one of course?

Can it be done using bash script, shell and some particular GTK interface (i'm targeting Gnome3 desktop environment for testing purposes)?

I would implement this in C or Java latter and i just need some basic hints on a native level as this is my first Linux desktop learning step.

Comment: Maybe check out how the GNOME folks do it in their [Screenshot](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gnome-screenshot/) program.  The source code is very compact.  I don't know if that will help you.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a start, i'll take a look.